# Add image from photo library from button and show the photo on the button

Tags: ios, swift

I couldn't really find an answer anywhere so I was wondering if someone could help me in this case;

I am looking for a way of how to import a photo from the photo library by pressing a (imageview-button) by either making the imageView clickable or adding an image to the UIbutton... either way, when you've imported the file, the photo should be displayed on this image/button view...

The app is made in Swift so I would appreciate if someone could share something in swift :-).

any help is appreciated!

Best regards
Strawhat.

Comment: I don't know whether asking for final solution is the way to go, but here is an easy tutorial of a easy component "UIImagePickerController" http://www.codingexplorer.com/choosing-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift/

Comment: "adding an image to the `UIButton`" You don't have to add an `imageView` to the `UIButton`. `UIButton` has an imageView by default. And you can access it like `myButton.imageView`

Comment: Use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) or [Photos](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos) to get the image you want, and put it into your button.

Comment: How about the actionhandler for this? I mean there is an actionhandler for picking the image from the library and a view for viewing (setting the photo) to the button view? or does the UIImagePickerController work like an action controller to recieve the image from the library and then I could set the image like myButton.imageView = imageFromLibrary??

Answer (score 1):

Following the tutorial suggested by Lepidopteron, use this

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        button.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        button.imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```